# Stopping jQuery JSON array loop after last row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am retrieving a JSON array and displaying the results as a list that is **ten** items long. However, if there are less than ten results found then it loops over with the first row again.

My code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.entertainmentcocktail.com/cp/index.php?area=bn2',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){

        var n = 0;

        while(n<10){            
        $.each(data, function(i,item){
            var places = item.name +
            ' where you can get' +
            ' a pint of <em>'+item.pint+'</em> for only ' +
            '<span>£'+item.cost+'!</span>';
            $('#placeList').append('<li id="listitem">'+ places +'</li>');
            n++;
        });
        }
    }
});
```

How can I get the code to display either the first ten rows **OR** all rows received depending on which is fewer?

Comment: Get rid of the `while` statement. $.each will only iterate over each object found, in the parent level of `data`. If it only has 10, it will iterate 10 times, if it only has 5, it will iterate 5 times and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your super fast reply, and it's working fine. However, if there are more than ten responses, how can I stop after the tenth one?

Comment: your each statement has the `i` index so `if (i < 10)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
success: function(data, status){    
    $.each(data, function(i,item){
        var places = item.name +
        ' where you can get' +
        ' a pint of <em>'+item.pint+'</em> for only ' +
        '<span>£'+item.cost+'!</span>';
        if (i < 10) {
            $('#placeList').append('<li id="listitem">'+ places +'</li>');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how he makes sure that only 10 li-s are appended (if more are returned)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's halfway there - I wanted it to also stop after 10 iterations, so I can put `if(i<=10)` around it. Thanks!

Comment: @BenPearlKahan just remember is it 0 indexed.. so if it you use `<= 10` you will get the `11th` item

Comment: Fixed for your requirement.

Comment: Or simply `$.each(data.slice(0,10), ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that `while`.

```
$.each(data, function(i,item){
  if(i >= 10) return;

  var places = item.name +
    ' where you can get' +
    ' a pint of <em>'+item.pint+'</em> for only ' +
    '<span>£'+item.cost+'!</span>';
    $('#placeList').append('<li id="listitem">'+ places);
});
```

(there are probably smarter ways to do what you're trying to do, but this is a quick fix of your code)

Comment: If you do `return false;`, you will also stop `.each` (which is even better :)).